# A First Order Nonlinear ODE1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this 1st order nonlinear ode $(y')^3-4 y'=C$

Can anyone help me with this?

Appreciated!

Comment: How about trying the Ansatz - $y(x) = Ax$ and finding the appropriate value for $A$?

Answer (score 0):

As written $y'$ is a constant $A$ solution of the equation $A^3-4A=C$ making $$y=Ax+c_1$$ Now, to get the value of $A$, just use the solution of cubic equations. Depending on the value of $C$, you could have, in the real domain, one, two or three roots.

Answer (score 0):

Set $y(x)=Ax+c_1$ where both $A,c_1$ are constant, now $y'=A$ solve your equation $A^3-4A=C$ to find $A$ and done, if you have information about the value of $y(x)$ at some value $x$ you can also get $c_1$ after you have $A$.